# How long am I supposed to wait to do something after I call WebBrowser.Refresh?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, webbrowser-control

I have a web page that I am tearing elements out of for use in a program I am writing. It takes a moment for a particular element to load into the web page, so I thought I would use `WebBrowser.Refresh()` in order to accomplish getting the up to date code.
Unfortunately doing so causes a whole lot of headache if you want to do ANYTHING afterwards since it doesn't fire the `DocumentCompleted` event (before anyone asks, it even says that explicitly on the MSDN).

So I need a method to allow the program like 2 seconds of doing nothing after it refreshes the page. The problem is that I don't know how to do that and be able to get the updated `WebBrowser.Document`. If I use Thread.Sleep, the entire application hangs while it sleeps and nothing gets updated.

And if I immediately try, I invariable get the crappy crappy problem of the WebBrowser object hanging forever or throwing Null Cast exceptions.

Has anyone else had this sort of problem (or something similar) and found a solution?

Comment: Does `WebBrowser.IsBusy` not work? Also, what about the `WebBrowser.ReadyState`?

Comment: No and no. Both of them fail to execute for some reason. IsBusy throws a Null Cast and so does ReadyState.

Comment: What do you mean they throw a null cast? Just accessing them throws it? Also, the reason why your app hangs when you sleep is because you are sleeping on the UI thread. You need to sleep in some background thread and notify the UI thread when its ready.

Comment: I mean that, when I go into the debug mode, every single parameter, method, and whatever else have you that is in the web browser control has a red ! next to it and says that it timed out and can't be accessed until execution is resumed, and the program throws an unhandled NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just navigate to the URL again?

```
   webBrowser1.Navigate(webBrowser1.Url);
```

This will fire the event handlers that you need.

Comment: Tried that too. The page is generated with PHP and it can change in real time rather than remain static which may be what is causing the problem. Is there a special way of handling PHP generated web pages?

Comment: This works as long as the URL doesn't include a bookmark hash, i.e. `http://example.com/#hash`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235700/) in getting a `WebBrowser` to refresh at a desired time. As you are discovering, it is hopeless to try to get it to refresh on demand; the HTTP response and HTML rendering are both non-deterministic.

My advice is to attach to the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event of the `WebBrowser`, call the desired web page early in the background and show the user something to distract them, then show the completed `WebBrowser` after `DocumentCompleted` fires.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be lazy and not use background threads:

```
wb.Refresh();
while ((wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)) {
    Application.DoEvents();
}
//Refresh is now complete
```

`ReadyState` should only be `WebBrowserReadyState.Complete` once all Ajax and content has completed loading.